# VBA Macro pointing across worksheets - fully qualified?

Tags: vba, excel

This macro works if my active worksheet is "Pipeline - Underwriting Data D" but not from any other worksheet.

I'm assuming it's because I'm incorrectly qualifying something?

Any help in tweaking the code so that it will run without selecting/activating the worksheet in question would be very much appreciated!

```
Dim pipe As Integer
With Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
    pipe = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With

With Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
    Dim Containword As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(pipe + 1, 14))
    Containword = "Outside Counsel"
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.find(Containword) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: change your `Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(pipe + 1, 14))` to `Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 14), .Cells(pipe + 1, 14))`

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much.  Can you articulate why that worked?  This will help me in the future.  Many thanks!

Comment: One more thing, you are mixing a `For Each cell In rng.Cells` with `Find` method, it doesn't make any sense using the `Find` if you are looping each cell. Either use the `Find`, or if you decide to loop through the cells use `If cell.Value = Containword  Then cell.Clear`

Comment: @Mat'sMug : You should specify that is free and open source, or you'll get flagged! ;) I still have to install it someday!^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "." for your "With" block that would point to the right range. See below:

```
Dim pipe As Integer
With Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
    pipe = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With

With Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D")
    Dim Containword As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 14), .Cells(pipe + 1, 14))
    Containword = "Outside Counsel"
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.find(Containword) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
    Next cell
End With
```